# Is there a way to figure out what device font Flex/Flash Player uses?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have a Flex 3 application in which embedded fonts were being used. However, due to licensing restrictions, I have to remove the embedded fonts. Not a big problem, but now legal wants to know which device font is being used? Seems like I can only provide them a list of "suggested" fonts from my CSS file and not the actual font that will be used at runtime.

See the note from Adobe @ http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_02.html:

> If the client's system does not have the first font in the list, Flash Player attempts to find the second, and so on, until it finds a font that matches. If no fonts match, Flash Player makes a best guess to determine which font the client uses.

How can I determine the font that the Flash Player ultimately ends up using?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the TextField where the font is applied should give you want you want.

```
var tff:TextFormat = yourTextField.defaultTextFormat
trace(tff.font)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this doesn't seem to work. Even though I specify "Verdana" in my stylesheet, the above code spits out the font as "Times New Roman".

Comment: are you sure when you type in the text field Verdana is applied to the new letters?